# C - Piping program output

Tags: c, unix

My program needs to read the output of `ls -l` and determine which files are directories. So I tried `ls -l | my_program.c`, but nothing happens and it should return two directories that I made. How do I read the input given from `ls -l`?

Comment: `my_program.c` isn't your program, its just your sourcecode, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Dude, first read some tutorials about the C programming language and only then approach such tasks. Your source file isn't the executable. That's ridiculous.

Comment: Is there a reason you're going with text processing from another tool? Directory listing is an OS dependent task, but then, so is `ls`. It would be much simpler to, on POSIX systems, to use [`opendir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir), [`readdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) and [`closedir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/closedir) to iterate the directory programmatically (and on most systems, the `dirent` struct will include `d_type` that will let you know if the entry is a directory "for free"; no need to `stat` unless you need to handle symlinks to dirs as dirs).

Comment: Learn [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

compile the program like this

```
gcc my_program.c -o my_program
```

then do

```
ls -l | my_program
```

Answer (score 1):

Before running, you have to compile your program. For C files, you can compile using gcc.

```
$ gcc my_program.c
```

This will create an executable file named a.out. Running is done by the following command.

```
$ ls -l | a.out
```

Comment: OP does not state he uses Linux. On POSIX systems, the C compiler is `c99`.

Comment: my 10c is that he uses linux